# Laravel 4 render view AJAX html is empty

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

```
public function index($id)
{   
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

    if(Request::ajax())
        { 

        $html = View::make('Milestones.indexpartial', $project)->render();

        return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
    }

    return View::make('milestones.index')->with('project', $project)
    ->with('title','Milestones');

}

$(".ajaxul a").click(function()
 {

   var url = $(this).attr('href');

   $.ajax(
 {
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    datatype: "html",
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $('#ajaxloading').show();
    }
  })
  .done(function(data)
  {
    $('#ajaxloading').hide();
    $(".refresh").empty().html(data.html);
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
  {
      alert('No response from server');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Please help me make this work.
I'm new to AJAX and laravel.

my problem was this line here:

```
   $html = View::make('Milestones.indexpartial', $project)->render();
```

it gives an error. then i changed it to

```
    $html = View::make('Milestones.indexpartial',array('project' => $project))->render();
```

the request is a success but the html is empty.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: When I was starting with laravel and tried to use ajax I was given the advice to leave the ajax out until you have a good understanding of how laravel does things and the order that everything occurs in

Comment: are you returning $html? like `return $html;` at the end of your function?